# Need to format two unl files in unix

Tags: unix, informix

I have two unl files..
sample.unl
test.unl
if i use the below cat command, my output is not properly formatted.

```
{
cat sample.unl
echo
cat test.unl
}
```

.

```
store_nbr   country_code    date    
400  CA 2010-06-11 12:00:49
```

I want the output to be in proper alignment like below..

```
store_nbr             country_code               date   
400                   CA                         2010-06-11 12:00:49
```

please help me..
Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between these two pieces of text?

Comment: first one has header only of the table,second unl has table output data..

Comment: You should be aware that `cat` is not a text formatter.  The data is properly handled by `cat`, but you are not using an appropriate tool for the task you want done.

Answer (score 1):

Write small python script for that:

```
$ cat format.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, re

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print "%-20s %-20s %-20s" % tuple(re.split('\s+', line.rstrip('\n'), 2))
```

Usage example:

```
$ python format.py sample.unl
store_nbr            country_code         date                
400                  CA                   2010-06-11 12:00:49
```

Comment: what do you mean? you want to do this without python?

Comment: @user1509613: Python is one script language that can do it conveniently; Perl and Awk are two others. Your unload file seems to be missing proper delimiters between fields which is going to make life hell -- unless there are tabs between the fields. You'll need to be careful about which tool you use, but the basic technique of reformatting the data using a command that will provide fixed width outputs is correct. It will be fun if your data contains newlines or tabs or other things that wreck the simple 'line-per-record' approach (blobs containing very variable length data; VARCHAR(2000)).